# Return whole cell rather than row

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to convert a year to a date representing the start of financial year.

```
HR$FYStart <- paste0(c(HR$FY,"06","30"), collapse = "-")
```

However instead of this importing `"2016-06-30"` and the like, it's getting every year value `"2016-2015-2014...-2016-2016-2016-2016-2016-2016-2016-2016-2016-06-30"`

I understand what it's doing and how it's interpreting my request - `HR$FY` is providing the whole column instead of just the relevant data point0.

How do I express what I'm meaning though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `paste` (not `paste0`), and specify dash as the separator character:

```
years <- c("2001", "2002", "2003")
paste(years, "06", "03", sep="-")

[1] "2001-06-30" "2002-06-30" "2003-06-30"
```

The `collapse` option will concatenate together the entire output from `paste`.  In your case, it would use dash as separator.  But what you really want is to separate the date components by dash, but retain each date as an entry in a vector.

Then use `paste` with a separator to achieve this.  Another issue you are having is that `paste0` by definition does not take a separator.  There are times when we want this behavior, but in your case, you don't want it.

### Demo

Comment: Hahaha was almost putting that up

Comment: No, the main issue was the use of `collapse` which does exactly what he observed.

Comment: @Roland But then what output does the OP actually want?  This isn't clear to me.

Comment: OP wants what you show. I was just giving further information.

Comment: @Roland ... right answer, wrong explanation.  I tried to clean it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks, for your help. Another part of my issue it appears was adding a column 'c()' to the paste function. I'd fiddled with sep and paste but showing me not to use the column pushed it over the line :)